# Return result of Action to Function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to return a value from an Action, but I am getting two errors:

> Using the generic type 'List<T>' requires 1 type arguments

and

> 'DataManager.MissionData' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

`GameSmart.sdk.LoadData()` loads data from our web server using the `WWW` class. I would like to return the response in the Action and save it in the `data` variable and have `LoadDataFromGameSmart` return that data.

```
public Type LoadDataFromGameSmart<Type>(){
    Type data = default(Type);
    Debug.Log ("Loading Data from GameSmart");
    GameSmart.sdk.LoadData(List<MissionData> data = (LoadDataResponse response) => {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<GSWrapper>(response.data).missionData;
    });
    return data;
}

[System.SerializableAttribute]
public class GSWrapper {

    public List<MissionData> missionData;

    public static GSWrapper CreateFromJSON(string jsonString){
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<GSWrapper>(jsonString);
    }
}
```

**LoadData** looks like this:

```
public void LoadData(Action<LoadDataResponse> onComplete = null){
    if(!IsValid()){return;}
    Send(endpoint_loadData, onComplete);
}
protected void Send<T>(string endpoint, Action<T> onComplete = null){
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    StartCoroutine(Request(endpoint, form, onComplete));
}
IEnumerator Request<T>(string endpoint, WWWForm form, Action<T> onComplete = null){
    form.AddField("playToken", playToken);
    WWW www = new WWW((protocol + "://" + GetHostName() + api_path) + endpoint, form);
    yield return www;
    if(onComplete != null){
        onComplete(JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(www.text));
    }
}
```

I have tried using:

```
GameSmart.sdk.LoadData(Func<Type> data = (LoadDataResponse response) => {
    return JsonUtility.FromJson<GSWrapper>(response.data).missionData;
});
```

But then I get this error:

> Using the generic type 'Func<TResult>' requires 1 type arguments

Not sure if this is relevant, but here is the `MissionData` class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class MissionData
{
    public int ID;//the ID of the Mission
    public bool isLocked = true;
    public List<LevelData> levelsData = new List<LevelData> ();//the levels of the mission

    /// <summary>
    /// Find the level data by ID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The level data.</returns>
    /// <param name="ID">the ID of the level.</param>
    public LevelData FindLevelDataById (int ID)
    {
        foreach (LevelData levelData in levelsData) {
            if (levelData.ID == ID) {
                return levelData;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

So, how can I return the result of the Action so that `LoadDataFromGameSmart` can return the final result?

Comment: `GameSmart.sdk.LoadData(List<MissionData> data = ...);` doesn't look like valid C# syntax. Are you trying to declare a new variable called `data` at that spot? If not, why mention the type `List<MissionData>`?

Comment: Removing that give this error: `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Type' because it is not a delegate type`

Comment: What's the signature of `LoadData`? Is there any documentation about what it expects?

Comment: I have added the LoadData function.

Comment: There are several problems here. First off, why are you involving the variable `data` in that call? Second, what you're passing is a `Func<LoadDataResponse, object>` (or something analogous), when `LoadData` is asking for an `Action<LoadDataResponse>`. An `Action` cannot `return` a value. (You could say that having an `Action<T>` is pretty much like having a `Func<T, void>`, except the second is illegal in C#, hence the need for a separate `Action` type.)

Comment: So, `Func<T>` specifies that it returns the type T.  If you want to pass a variable to it, you have to use `Func<TParam,TResult>`.  By convention, the last type is the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct:

```
public Type LoadDataFromGameSmart<Type>(){
    Type data = default(Type);
    Debug.Log ("Loading Data from GameSmart");
    GameSmart.sdk.LoadData(List<MissionData> data = (LoadDataResponse response) => {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<GSWrapper>(response.data).missionData;
    });
    return data;
}
```

Some of the issues:

1. data is defined twice (once as `Type`, once as `List<MissionData>`)
2. `LoadData(List<MissionData> data` is invalid syntax.
3. `LoadData` expects an `Action`, but you are returning data
4. Your template `Type` has no constraints, as as such cannot be converted to `List<MissionData>`
5. `(LoadDataResponse response)` should be `(response)` - you don't define argument types when passing a lambda - they're defined by `LoadData's signature` in this case

You can try something like this:

```
public List<MissionData> LoadDataFromGameSmart()
{
   List<MissionData> data = null;
   Debug.Log ("Loading Data from GameSmart");
   GameSmart.sdk.LoadData(
    (response) => {
        data = JsonUtility.FromJson<GSWrapper>(response.data).missionData;
   });
   return data;
}
```

Assuming `LoadData` is *blocking*, this will return the data properly.

Comment: I don't believe LoadData is blocking. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn In that case, you have two options: Make `LoadDataFromGameSmart` blocking until `LoadData` completes, or have `LoadDataFromGameSmart` take a callback method (much like `LoadData` does)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Is `LoadData` (and the rest) written by you? Can they be changed? Avoiding `yield return` would make it a regular method (instead of a coroutine).

Comment: The main application was purchased. I am trying to implement our api into it. And the way it was written the function that calls  `LoadFromGameSmart` expects a value to be returned. If it is null it saves a default set of data. Since this returns null. It overwrites the data on the server with the default.

Comment: And yes I can change anything in the entire program and the API

Comment: I think an Action can't have a return can it? Should be a `Func`

Comment: @GunnarB. That's correct - there's no return here though, it's a callback

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn It depends entirely on how `StartCoroutine` runs non-blocking. I'm not familiar at all with unity, so I can't help you there. However, a naive way to do it would be to spin up a thread which continually checks that `data` was set. I'd advise against this however, unless it's a last resort. I would either check if Unity provides a way to check on the co-routines status - or I would return data in a callback in the exact same way `LoadData` does.

Comment: I fixed this, I had to rewrite some of the code in the main app to listen for the `WWW` call to finish. When it does, I then move on to the next steps.